# Why my context menu options desapear after I added the sharepoint list to a page and hold commandbar of the list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom-actions

folks.
I've created a context menu custom action for my sharepoint list, but when I added the list to a page and switched "Hold command bar" to hide it - I can't see my custom action anymore.
Does any body know something about it?
Thanks

Comment: When you hide the command bar, all the options at the top of list will be hidden.

Comment: @GaneshSanap - Even context menu?